# Protractor Single Page application test

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, protractor

In Angular JS Single Page Application, ui router is configured to change the view content (`<ui-view></ui-view>`) based on the state of the application.

How do we test the changed view content (pages) in protractor? The view content is not displayed while doing page source view. Page is loaded correctly, but the protractor cannot find the page elements.

```
<head>
    <title> Test Application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <ui-view></ui-view>
        </div>
    <div>
<body>
```

Snippet code that goes inside `<ui-view></ui-view>`

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="firstName" class="ng-scope">First Name</label>
<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName"  ng-model="customer.firstName">
</div>
```

Protractor cannot find the elements **by.model**.

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
        browser.get('http://example.com');//url
        it("Test..", function() {
        element(by.model('customer.firstName')).sendKeys('FIRSTNAME');
        element(by.model('customer.lastName')).sendKeys('LASTNAME');
       });
    });
```

Comment: When you use the dev-tools in for example Chrome you should see the html that is inserted in the `<ui-view>`, can you also paste a piece of code here, from the dev-tools, so we can help you further with your question?

Comment: can you please include the code from protractor test

Answer (score 0):

Possible that it's looking for the elements before they've been loaded in and is therefore missing them. Try using `protractor.ExpectedConditions`. For example:

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
    browser.get('http://example.com');
    it("Test..", function() {
        var el = element(by.css('.form-group'));
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(el), 10000).then(function(){
            element(by.model('customer.firstName')).sendKeys('FIRSTNAME');
            element(by.model('customer.lastName')).sendKeys('LASTNAME');
        });
    });
});
```

Here it will wait a maximum of 10 seconds for the `.form-group` div to be present on the page before attempting to fill in the inputs.

Comment: Stack:
    ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible

Comment: How big is the page these elements are on? Is it big enough that the elements are not in the viewport when protractor is looking for it perhaps?